# Preserving uniqueness of a system when adding a constant

Tags: systems-of-equations, game-theory

I have a complete information static game with a **concave** twice differentiable objective function $F_i(x_1,...,x_n;\beta)$ with player $i=1...n$ choosing non negative arguments $x_i\geq 0$, where $\beta$ are parameters. The system of necessary and sufficient first order conditions are:

$f_1(x_1,...,x_n;\beta)=0,....,f_n(x_1,...,x_n;\beta)=0$

**I know** that this system of equations has a unique solution (unique pure strategy Nash equilibrium), implying that I can write each $x_i=h_i(\beta)$, where $h_i$ is a function.

**Now I add** a constant $\alpha>0$ to each equation:

$f_1(x_1,...,x_n;\beta)+\alpha=0,....,f_n(x_1,...,x_n;\beta)+\alpha=0$

My question is whether this system still has a unique solution, meaning whether I can write $x_i=g_i(\beta,\alpha)$, where $g_i$ is a function.

I have tried this on a few games like Cournot oligopoly and I'm still looking for some counterexample. I'm unsure of how to go about a proof if it's correct as working with fixed points is difficult.

(This is self-study, not a homework question).

Comment: Please add some game-theoretic context to elucidate the tag (game-theory).

Comment: @mlc do my edits help?

Comment: I am not sure your edits suffice. We can make up what is missing, yes, but most people prefer to answer clearly defined questions.

Comment: @mlc what is unclear?